# Butter made out of pasteurized cream?

Tags: butter

I got a pat of "butter" today at a restaurant and the wrapper said that it contained "pasteurized cream" and salt. Is pasteurized cream the same thing as butter?

Comment: The question here then would be is the pasteurized cream *added* to the butter before packaging or noted as what the butter was *made from.* The restaurant might know.

Answer (score 5):

No, cream and butter are not the same thing. Butter is made by agitating cream, causing the fat to clump up and separate from the rest of the cream. The butter is then washed, optionally salted, and pressed. So the “ingredients” of butter are cream and optionally salt.

Pasteurization is a process for inactivating microorganisms in foods  like milk and cream by heating them to a fairly high temperature for a short period of time. It has the effect of increasing shelf life and reducing the risk of food-borne illness. All dairy products you buy at the grocery store, with the possible exception of some fancy cheeses, have been pasteurized.

Comment: Nitpick : cheeses don't have to be fancy to be unpasteurized, Comté, Brie and Reblochon (to name a few) are fairly common cheeses in France that are made with raw milk.

Comment: @PierreCathé A nice illustration of different cheese cultures (no pun intended); I get the impression those would all be considered 'fancy' in the US, where the OP is based. A good reminder of the varied world we're all writing in!

Comment: In addition, the brand of brie one would most commonly encounter there is made of pasteurized milk.